# XAMARIN: WebView Loads Links Half-Way Down the Page (or keeps position?)

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

I've got this code for creating a WebView:

```
public class SessionsActivity : Activity
{

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.discover);

      //declare webview and tell our code where to find the XAML resource
      WebView discoverWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewDiscover);

      //set the webview client
      discoverWebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      //load the subscription url
      discoverWebView.LoadUrl("https://www.bitchute.com/");
      //enable javascript in our webview
      discoverWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
      //zoom control on?  This should perhaps be disabled for consistency?
      //we will leave it on for now
      discoverWebView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
      discoverWebView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
      //scrollbarsdisabled
      // subWebView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
      discoverWebView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
  }
}
```

but when I click on links inside my app, the page loads at the same spot as the last page was, which makes navigation very difficult, because mobile pages are supposed to load from the top, not from the middle.  So basically, if I am in my subscriptions feed, and then I scroll down to find more content, I click on a user, and their video page loads videos from weeks ago, because it loaded with the same view elevation as the root page.

The site I'm using `WebView` with is also designed for mobile users, if that matters.  The weird thing is that this used to not happen until recently... don't know what changed. How can I have the `WebView` load at top of page on each click?

I'm using `TabHost` for this .. here's my full code for context

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_a2/blob/2.68/MainActivity.cs

thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I made small edits to your question to make it more readable. You should isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, be sure to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: How can I debug it when there is no exception?  I don't see page load coordinates in the stack either.  I don't know how I can give a better example... it's clear what I'm asking, and I'm not in a hurry to get this fixed.  I'm just wondering if any other xamarin users have seen this or know what to do about it.  This is a super niche question; so if the coder hasn't seen the issue, they're probably going to have no idea; but once this is resolved, the answer will be available for future developers.

Comment: This happens because of the scrollview.  I did not find any way to stop the page loading halfway down other than removing the scrollview.  I tried manually assigning ScrollView.ScrollY = 0; and that did nothing.  

this app uses the ScrollView:

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_a2

this app uses no scrollview:

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav

pages don't load halfway down in the latter

Comment: stack won't let me answer my own questions when noone else will, very lame... thanks a lot.  You don't answer my questions then I can't post the solutions to my own.  That's sweet

Comment: hi @hexagod, random person here, sorry you didn't get an answer yet. I don't know anything about xamarin but saw an opportunity to help with formatting to make the question more legible and hopefully give you a higher chance for a response. I meant no disrespect, and If you want I can undo my change. also you should totally be able to answer your own question, that's even encouraged! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)  Best of luck.

Comment: @lucascaro yeah no worries.  Your edit was good.  My point was that my answering ability was disabled but my post got edited lol.  I'm over it, not a big deal

Comment: @hexagod Why can't you answer your own question? Do you get an error or something when you try? Asking because self answering is encouraged on SO and you should be able to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @ModusTollens "low quality answers" I guess